# MLE of a Pareto distribution with $X_{i} \sim PAR(1,\kappa)$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistical-inference

> I'm trying to find the MLE based on a random sample $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ from this following distribution
>
> $X_{i} \sim PAR(1,\kappa)$

This is my work so far

$$f(x;\kappa) = \frac{\kappa}{(1+x_{i})^{1+\kappa}}$$
$$L(\kappa) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\kappa}{(1+x_{i})^{1+\kappa}}$$
$$\ln L = n \ln \kappa - (1+\kappa)\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln (1+x_{i})$$
$$0 = \frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \kappa} = \frac{n}{\kappa} - ... $$

I don't know how to continue can anyone help?

Comment: It's unclear where you're having trouble. Is it calulating the derivative of the second term? After that it's just solving for $\kappa.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am having trouble calculating the derivative of the second term.  I don't know what to do with the summation term

Comment: Just think of $C = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1+x_i)$ as a number. Note it doesn't depend on $\kappa.$ So you can write the term $(1+\kappa)C.$ This is easy to differentiate, right?

Comment: Oh lol it is just $C$ then, so $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln (1+x_{i})$?

Comment: yep that's right.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I solved for the estimator and got $\displaystyle\widehat{\kappa} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(1+x_{i})}$

Comment: yep that's right.